# How to sort an Array of Date.prototype.toLocaleString() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, date, locale

I have an array of Dates which is of format Date.prototype.toLocaleString('en-GB'). How can I sort these string based dates ?

example input: ["22/07/2020, 8:54:09 AM", "23/07/2020, 9:54:09 AM", "22/08/2020, 8:54:09 AM",...]

```
transform(list: any, columnProperty: ColumnProperties, order: string): any {
  if (!list || !columnProperty) {
    return list;
  }
  let orderVal1 = 1;
  let orderVal2 = -1;
  if (columnProperty.sortValue === DESC) {
    orderVal1 = -1;
    orderVal2 = 1;
  }
  list.sort((a, b) => {
    a = a[columnProperty.fieldName];
    b = b[columnProperty.fieldName];
    if(isNaN(a) && !isNaN(Date.parse(a)) && isNaN(b) && !isNaN(Date.parse(b))) {
      var da = new Date(a).toISOString(), 
      db = new Date(b).toISOString();
      return da > db ? orderVal1 : ( da === db ? 0 : orderVal2 );
    }
    else {
      var va = (a === null) ? "" : "" + a,
      vb = (b === null) ? "" : "" + b;
    }

  return va > vb ? orderVal1 : ( va === vb ? 0 : orderVal2 );
  });
  return list;
}
```

expected output: ["22/07/2020, 8:54:09 AM", "23/07/2020, 9:54:09 AM", "22/08/2020, 8:54:09 AM",...]

actual output: ["22/07/2020, 8:54:09 AM", "22/08/2020, 8:54:09 AM", "23/07/2020, 9:54:09 AM",...]

Here I used parse to find if the inputs are in Date format, as I may get other types as well like String, numbers, etc.
The above code works well if my inputs are UTC Date or date.toLocaleString('en-US'). As the format is d/mm/yyyy, but when I use other locale formats it never worked.

I tried the following,

1. Tried to convert the localeString back to UTC just for sorting purpose, but unfortunately couldn't find an utility for that.
2. I can't sort the Array in prior as I need this functionality to be dynamic.
3. Requirement is to order the dates in different locations based on the browser locale they have.

Any help on this is much appreciated

Comment: do you really want them ordered by the string values (so e.g. 01-01-2000 is before 02-01-2000. since '01' is < '02')? or ordered by the actual date value? Because your expected output ```["22/07/2020, 8:54:09 AM", "23/07/2020, 9:54:09 AM", "22/08/2020, 8:54:09 AM",...]``` is not ordered by string-ordering

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting order by Date, Actually the conversion from localeString to Date is where the issue is, as it always expects the d/m/yyyy format. If the Date is 31/12/2020, it shows Invalid Date and considered as a String ordering, as my code does the String sort as well

Answer (score 0):

Parse to locale date strings via momentjs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ to Date objects.
Then in the sort function compare (`<`/`>`) the numeric date values with `a.valueOf()` and `b.valueOf()` instead of comparing the ISO-strings.